# R: Paste spacing in a data.frame

Tags: r, paste

I have a dataframe `u` in which I want to paste other columns to the column `NAME`

```
u <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1", "NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),PU=c("CH","CH","CH","CH","AU","AU","AU"),ID=c(47,47,47,47,259,259,259),YEAR=c(1932,1942,1965,1989,2007,2008,2014),VALUE=c(0,NA,-6,-16,0,-9,-28))

u

 NAME PU  ID YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 CH  47 1932     0
2 NAME1 CH  47 1942    NA
3 NAME1 CH  47 1965    -6
4 NAME1 CH  47 1989   -16
5 NAME2 AU 259 2007     0
6 NAME2 AU 259 2008    -9
7 NAME2 AU 259 2014   -28

# paste columns PU and ID into column NAME 
u$NAME <-paste(u$NAME, u$PU, '(ID:',u$ID,')')
```

What I am attempting to do is to paste it in the following format eg for the first row:
NAME1 CH (ID: 47) however using my code above I get NAME1 CH (ID: 47 )

How could I get rid of the space between the ID number and the closing bracket? I tried using `sep=""` which failed as well...

```
u$NAME <-paste(u$NAME, u$PU, '(ID:',u$ID,')', sep="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try: (if I am not mistaken)

Using your code, try with `regex` to remove the extra `space` after the `)`

```
  gsub(" (?=\\))", "",paste(u$NAME, u$PU, '(ID:',u$ID,')'), perl=TRUE)
  #[1] "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)" 
  #[4] "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)" "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)"
  #[7] "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)"
```

Here, I used `lookahead` to match a `space` followed by `)` i.e. `" (?=\\))"` and replace it with `""`.

Or

```
  paste(paste(u$NAME, u$PU), paste0("(ID: ", u$ID, ")"))
 #[1] "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)" 
 #[4] "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)" "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)"
 #[7] "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)"
```

Or

```
  with(u, paste0(paste(NAME, PU, "(ID:", ID),")"))
 # [1] "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)" 
 #[4] "NAME1 CH (ID: 47)"  "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)" "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)"
 #[7] "NAME2 AU (ID: 259)"
```

Comment: Or `paste0(u$NAME, " ", u$PU, " (ID: ", u$ID, ")")`

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for the code.  I was trying to shorten it to one `paste` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
u$NAME <-paste(u$NAME, " ", u$PU, " (ID: ", u$ID, ")", sep="")
```

Explanation: just paste all of the strings together with "" as the separator and be make sure you include extra white space when needed.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Explain so other then questioner can understand.

Comment: This is actually the exact copy of @akruns last solution

Comment: My answer is different from akrun's last answer. However, I admit that I did not see Henrik's post, which is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sprintf`:

`with(u, sprintf('%s %s (ID: %d)', NAME, PU, ID))`

`%s` means that it will be replaced by a string and `%d` by an integer.